# Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'managedObjectContext'

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

```
func saveName(name: String){
   //1
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    //2
    let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
    //3
    person.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
    //4
    var error: NSError?
    if !managedContext.save(&error) {
        print("Could not save \(error!), \(String(describing: error?.userInfo))");
    }
    //5
    people.append(person)
}
```

I can't get this program working correctly. I was trying save to CoreData.

Comment: Does your `AppDelegate` class have a property named `managedObjectContext` (as your subject says) or maybe `managedContext` (as your code says)?

Comment: it has persistentContainer and saveContext. I should be using these instead right?

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift 3**, you access the context object like this:-

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

Comment: It looks like a combination of //1 and //2 line code that I was using. Let me try it out on my program.

Answer (score 0):

As the managed object context is used frequently add a lazy instantiated property in `AppDelegate`

```
lazy var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext = {
    return self.persistentContainer.viewContext
}()
```

Both `entity` and `managedObjectContext` are supposed to be non-optional.

Answer (score -1):

Change your second line in your code to access the managed object context

```
let managedContext = appDelegate.persistantContainer.Viewcontext
```

Comment: Please, don't you see it? Even the syntax highlighter shows you one of the mistakes immediately.